# skip=!count! is not working in windows(7) batch file

Tags: batch-file

In for loop i have checked condition, if condition is true i have set the count value and skipped some lines in file,

```
           @echo off
           SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
           set /a count=0
           set for_parameters="skip=!count! delims="
           for /f %for_parameters% %%a in ('list.txt') do (
               echo %%a
               if %%a==Exception: (
                   set /a count+=2
               )
           )
           Endlocal

  Its shows delims=" was unexpected at this time. Error
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem .....

Comment: Whoah.. 17 questions and not a single accepted answer :-( If you get a good answer to one of your questions, please accept it by clicking on the check mark near the upper left corner of the answer. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 rep points, and awards the answer poster 15 rep points. Only 1 answer can be accepted per question. You can up vote as many answers as you find useful, even answers to other people's questions. An up vote awards 10 points to the answer poster. You can also up vote questions, awarding 5 points to the poster.

Answer (score 4):

What jeb said about delayed expansion and FOR options is true - you can't use it - but that has nothing to do with the problem in your code.

You are using delayed expansion before you use the expression in your FOR statement, so there is no problem there.

Your problem is that you are attempting to set SKIP=0. The SKIP value must be >0 to be valid. The fix is simple: don't include the SKIP option if you don't want to skip any lines :-)

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=0
set "skip="
if !count! gtr 0 set "skip=skip=!count!"
set for_parameters="!skip! delims="
for /f %for_parameters% %%a in ('list.txt') do (
    echo %%a
    if %%a==Exception: (
        set /a count+=2
    )
)
Endlocal
```

Expanding on jeb's point: you cannot do the following

```
for /f !for_parameters! %%a in ...
```

because FOR has special parsing rules. Most commands parse their options after delayed expansion. But FOR and IF parse their options before FOR variable expansion and delayed expansion take place. Neither FOR variables nor delayed expansion can be used to specify FOR or IF options.

Comment: Won't this still fail because of the reason you pointed out about skip needing to be > 0? On the first run `count` isn't incremented, so skip will still = 0?

Comment: @BaliC - Follow the logic - the SKIP variable is undefined if COUNT is 0, so the SKIP option never makes it into FOR_PARAMETERS.

Answer (score 1):

In the for-options you can only use percent expansion, but not delayed expansion.
If your skip value itself is calculated in a block, then you need to extract the for loop into a function

Comment: True jeb, but that is not the problem here :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the More command to skip lines.

```
@echo off

:: By Elektro H@cker

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a count=2

for /F %%a in ('Type "list.txt" ^| MORE +!COUNT!') do (echo %%a)

Pause&exit
```

Comment: You certainly *can* use MORE to skip lines. But you certainly don't *need* to use MORE. The MORE solution has limitations - It converts tabs to spaces, and I also believe it hangs once the file reaches a certain size.